# friend operator<< overloading in template class?

Tags: c++

I have a homework from university where I have to programm a template class with and overloaded friend output operator. But I am confused how to define it right with a template.
Making the overloaded funktion a friend doesn't make sense for me, because it isn't needed for the compiler to generate it for different classes, one function would work for all of them.

I hope someone can explain it or help me.

```
template <typename TValue>
class Queue {
public:
    explicit Queue(size_t const capacity);
    Queue(Queue const& copy);

    ~Queue();

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, Queue const& src);
    bool IsEmpty() const;

    void Enqueue(TValue val);
    TValue Dequeue();   
private:
    TValue* pArray;
    size_t in = 0;
    size_t out = 0;
    size_t capacity;

    bool LastDequed = true;
};
...
...
template <typename TValue>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const Queue<TValue>& src)
{
    //Print first value
    if (!src.IsEmpty())
    {
        ost << src.Dequeue();
    }
    //Print next values
    while (!src.IsEmpty())
    {
        ost << ", " << src.Dequeue();
    }       
    return ost;
}
```

This was my recent try/version, but it doesn't work either.

Thanks and Mfg,
Tropaion

Comment: Does this help:  `template <typename T> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, Queue<T> const& src);`

Comment: @user4581301 I think that it's not a duplicate of the link you showed. Here it's about a `friend operator<<` and not about a general friend function. The actual answer is slightly different than the answers in the link you mark as duplicate.

Comment: @KorelK Then we need different answers for an infinite number of functions. A function's a function, and the principle described in the link also works here. I know because I stupidly [wrote an answer before looking for a dupe](https://godbolt.org/z/jjo9e8). There is a slight difference with the `Dequeue` not being callable on a `const` `Queue`, but that's it.

Comment: @user4581301 I checked it, and it didn't compile until I added a `template<typename T>` above the declaration of the friend function. There is no mentioned for this in the link you marked as a dup. `template<typename T> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, Queue<T> &src);`. An operator overloading is not a regular function.

Comment: @KorelK Works for me is a crap answer with C++, but [works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/dK6ExG).

Comment: @user4581301 I see, although I got a lot more simpler solution: https://godbolt.org/z/h87enK, and I believe it's worth sharing.

Comment: @KorelK That brings it down to about as complex as option one in the duplicate. Vast improvement over what I was missing with.

Comment: @user4581301 I added the answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62834015/8038186 :)